# How does Express work?

Tags: express, mean-stack

I am learning MEAN stack and learnt how it starts like,

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('exress'),
    app = express();
app.listen(8080);
```

and I type node example.js on terminal then I can check it on the Web browser. If I stop process on terminal(in my case, it is ctrl + C), it does not show up on the Web browser. So I wonder if I use MEAN stack cloud server(like aws or digitalocean), should I have to keep terminal which connects cloud server on all the time, so that users can connect my website 24/7 via typing domain?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run node app process in the background , you run command line as below:

```
$nohup node simple-server.js > output.log &
```

Or you can use forever: http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever/

Comment: yes, you can close terminal after you run the command line above.